# How do I specify strike-through text style in Android?

Tags: android, text, styles

Hi I want to  write a word like "discount price" and cut it by straight line(not image) and write just below of "discount price" -> new discount price without cut it

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example from: http://fupeg.blogspot.com/2010/01/strikethrough-android.html

```
TextView someLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_label);
someLabel.setText(someDynamicString);
someLabel.setPaintFlags(someLabel.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
```